# HTML : Image in same line appearing slightly above text

Tags: html, css

Please see the example at [DEMO](http://bestsites.me/test.php) , It has following html code

```
helllo hello test test <img src="http://bestsites.me/img/bs.png">
```

You can see that image is slightly above text.How can i make the image to come little down.

Comment: use CSS margin property to image to get your desired result. with negative or positive values.. Eg: margin: 2px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is the best way of achieving this but you may use:

```
helllo hello test test <img src="http://bestsites.me/img/bs.png" style="margin-bottom: -7px;">
```

or you can edit your picture in some photo editing software (gimp, vs).

Comment: i have used many images , all images appears same like that, you can highlight the whole paragraph to see the pixel of images

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please mark answer as correct if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<p>hello hello test test<img src="image.png"/></p>
```

CSS:

```
p,img{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

The above should make sure the p and image element are inline with each other.

Another method:

HTML

```
<p>Hello Hello test test</p><img src='image.png'/>
```

CSS

```
p,img{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline-block;//not for ie 5.5-7?
    width:49%;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:top;
    border:1px solid #FF0000;//to check the positioning of the elements
    //these should now be completely level BUT this might not make the text 100% level
}
```

Comment: but still image is slightly above text ..Please check my demo link , i have updated code

Comment: @VishnuSimbu Check the edit. I added another method that might be a bit better. But as I put in the comments: might not make the text 100% level

Answer (score 0):

you can use
**`<img align='middle'>`**

Align middle will work for you

Aligning image with text should work.
**`<img src='src' align='middle'>`** 
will make you image to appear in the middle